# Finding path between all points using approximation algorithm

Tags: algorithm, path, coordinates, approximation

There is 1<=n<=1000 cities. I have to find path that connects all the cities (every city can be visited only once) which starts and ends in city number 1. In this path the maximum length between 2 cities must be as short as possible.

Eg:

[image]

Input:

```
coordinates of cities
```

Output:

```
5 1 3 //longest connection is 5 and it is between cities 1 and 3
1 3 6 4 5 2 1 //path
```

Comment: @phant0m, this is incorrect, as limitations different, "Max length" and "total sum".

Comment: Do you need a approximate algorithm? If so, you should add that to the question, and not just the title. I realized you needed an approximate algorithm from your tags, not the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an approximation algorithm that should give better results on average than a naive greedy algorithm:

1. Consider the graph to be complete - there is an edge between every pair of vertices for a total of `n(n-1)/2` edges.
2. Sort the edges in descending order of their weights/distances.
3. Iterate from the highest distance edge to the lowest distance edge, and remove it if after removing that edge, both its end-points still have degree atleast ceil(n/2) ([Dirac's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac%27s_theorem_on_Hamiltonian_cycles#Bondy.E2.80.93Chv.C3.A1tal_theorem) for ensuring a Hamiltonian cycle exists). You could use a stronger result like [Ore's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ore%27s_theorem) to be able to trim even more edges, but the computation complexity will increase.
4. In the remaining graph, use a greedy algorithm to find a Hamiltonian cycle. The greedy algorithm basically starts from 1, and keeps selecting the edge with the least distance to a node that does not already form part of the cycle so far. So in your example, it will first pick 1 -> 2, then 2->4, then 4->5 and so on. The last selected vertex will then have a path back to 1.

You could directly use the greedy algorithm given in step 4 on the input graph, but the pre-processing steps 1-3 should in general greatly improve your results on most graphs.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds similar to [TSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) except that you need to minimize the max length between 2 cities rather than the total (which probably makes it fundamentally different).

My thought is something like:

```
create edges between each pair of cities
while (true)
  next = nextLongestEdge
  if (graph.canRemove(next)) // this function may be somewhat complicated,
                             // note that it must at the very least check that every node has at least 2 edges
    graph.remove(next)
  else
    return any path starting and ending at 1 from the remaining edges
```

Comment: `this function may be somewhat complicated` I smiled :)

Comment: @phant0m Yeah, but I'm thinking it's a lot simpler than the original problem - you just need to find a single path from the remaining edges. It may help to add some intelligence to avoid DFS (e.g. if the degree of any vertex < 2, fail). Note that the higher the average degree, the more likely it is to find a solution quickly, the lower the average degree, the faster it runs.

Comment: @Dukeling For a correct algorithm, you would need to check that the graph is Hamiltonian after removing the edge, which is a NP-complete in general graphs. And your algorithm would be computing this for every call of `canRemove()`.

Comment: @Paresh For the first call of `canRemove` the graph will be so dense that DFS will return a result with backtracking at most once (thus O(m)). When the graph becomes sparse it will be a lot faster to calculate. For the first one, if you do the DFS favouring the shortest edges, you could get solution that will remain valid even if a few other edges are removed (which you can remember, and continue on from if it isn't valid any more (thus basically reducing it to solving a single instance)). But, yes, it will likely still be too slow.

Comment: @Dukeling DFS does not give a cycle. It gives a tree. You cannot use DFS to find a [Hamiltonian cycle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path). If you could, Hamiltonian cycle finding would not be NP-complete. Note that DFS is linear in the number of edges and vertices.

Comment: @Dukeling Just to clarify, the TSP is finding a Hamiltonian cycle of maximum total weight. You cannot solve it using DFS.

Comment: Check exists Hamiltonian cycle is possible, but find it is NP solution.